# Spring Tool Suite says it could not create BootDashView (or any Spring view)

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

When I go to the "Boot Dashboard" (**Update:** actually I see similar messages on each Spring view) view I see the message

> Could not create the view: org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.dash.views.BootDashView

There is an icon to see the error logs beside it, so I deleted them, reopened STS, and I did not see any error.

Any guidance on how to resolve this or further debug it?

---

### More info

After following Martin's advice and opening the Host OSGi Console and typing `ss` to get the short status and doing `diag <id>` on a few different things all I was ever able to get was similar to this,

> ```
> org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.dash [962]
>   No resolution report for the bundle.
> ```

Martin mentioned looking for `INSTALLED`, but all I saw were `ACTIVE`, `RESOLVED`, `STARTING`, and `<<LAZY>>`. I ran `diag` on at least one bundle of each state, but got nothing any different than above (of course the names and IDs were different).

Comment: Sounds like some features of the Spring tooling got disabled or corrupted after the install. Did you download the latest STS distribution? And did you install additional third-party plugins into that? Or did you install the STS components into an existing Eclipse installation? Some steps how to reproduce this would be helpful. In addition to that I could only recommend to download the STS distribution from here: https://spring.io/tools

Comment: @Martin I downloaded the official STS from their website, I've since added some plugins. It was working before so one of them probably conflicts with it somehow. This isn't really an issue for me, I just can't stand error messages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was facing the similar issue with Spring Boot Dash view and using `-clean` option and restart STS worked for me.

Comment: This didn't work for me (see comments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35514862/1858327)) but thank you for the answer as Martin did suggest it and it's nice to know it does work for some people.

Answer (score 1):

Just faced the same issue upgrading to latest STS 3.8.3 based on Neon.2 (4.6.2).  Starting with the `-clean` option did nothing for me, neither did uninstalling / reinstalling the Groovy Eclipse feature as [discussed](https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-4351).

What resolved it for me was **switching to a new clean workspace** - the boot dashboard then started working again.  Oddly, it also works if I now switch back to the old workspace.  Before this, the module was showing as `LAZY` in the Host OSGi console, now it's ACTIVE:

```
966 ACTIVE      org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.dash_3.8.3.201612191259-RELEASE
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was one of my Groovy Eclipse compiler plugins (it was 1.8, 1.9, 2.0, 2.1, or 2.2, not sure which). After uninstalling it the Boot Dashboard no longer has an error.

Since part of my question was wondering about how to get better insight into the problem (more than checking the error log, which was empty) I will not mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: That is interesting and I also would like to understand the exact issue in more detail here. To uncover more details, you could take a deeper look under the hood: Open a console view, switch it to the "OSGi Host Console", and type in "ss" for "short status". That returns a list of installed bundles. Look for bundles in the "INSTALLED" state. If you find some (maybe boot dashboard related), remember the number of the bundle and type "diag <number>". This will provide information why the dependencies of the bundle are not satisfied anymore - which might be the case in your situation.

Comment: @Martin I'm getting this problem again. I don't think I mentioned it before but it is *all* of the Spring views, not just boot dash. I still have a sneaking suspicion it's related to the Groovy Eclipse stuff as it's a snapshot (no release for Mars yet). When I get a chance I'll do those steps and update the question.

Comment: @Martin I've added some details in the question above, all I was able to get was `No resolution report for the bundle.`.

Comment: If there is no bundle in the "INSTALLED" state, that is a good sign... :-) Did you try to start your STS/Eclipse with option "-clean" ? Maybe that helps (just guessing here).

Comment: @MartinLippert "-clean" didn't help. I have since installed 3.7.3 with Eclipse Mars and once I imported a Maven project with Groovy I started getting these errors (simply having Groovy Eclipse plugin didn't cause any issues. I tried all the steps you told me with 3.7.3 to no avail.

Comment: Can you provide a few exact steps how to reproduce this from a plain STS 3.7.3 distribution install? Or a plain Eclipse Mars.2 install? If I have the exact steps (and sample projects), I might be able to reproduce this and analyze this issue in more detail on my machine.